# Height of background always 100 percent, even after scrolling

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below I try to get the grey background always 100%. But when you make the window smaller you will see that the background of `.b` becomes white. How can I fix this so that the background is always grey even when you make the window smaller and have to scroll?

Thanks.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.a {
  height: 100%
}

.b {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  height: 100%;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">Left 
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="c"> Right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `height` you can use `min-height`, check updated snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.a {
  height: 100%
}

.b {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  height: 100%;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">Left 
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="c"> Right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove   **height: 100%;** in .b style:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.a {
  height: 100%
}

.b {
  background: grey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  height: 100%;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">Left 
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    A lot of content <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="c"> Right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

remove      **height: 100%;**   in .b style

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

in .b class css make,

```
height: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bodys height 100% is not relative to anything, meaning that it's height will be fixed after the viewports height - remove the body height, then all of the other height will be auto and fall in line

Clerification

Your surrounding container (body) is not high enough to do this - Either get rid of that height, or make it higher.